# Why doesn't nix find python39?

Tags: python, installation, packaging, nix, nixos

I would like to install python 3.9 with nix (I am running nix 2.3.3 on NixOS 19.09.2166.ce9f1aaa39e (Loris)). It is defined  on NixOS/nixpkgs as [can be seen here](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/development/interpreters/python/default.nix#L106):

```yaml
  python39 = callPackage ./cpython {
    self = python39;
    sourceVersion = {
      major = "3";
      minor = "9";
      patch = "0";
      suffix = "";
    };
    sha256 = "0m18z05nlmqm1zjw9s0ifgrn1jvjn3jwjg0bpswhjmw5k4yfcwww";
    inherit (darwin) configd;
    inherit passthruFun;
  };
```

This section was last changed on 2020-10-13, 4 weeks ago. (Even the [not yet released Python 3.10](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3100a1/) can be found in this file)

Yet I can't find it with nix:

```
$ nix search -u python38 # is found
* nixpkgs.python38 (python3-3.8.0)
  A high-level dynamically-typed programming language

* nixpkgs.python38Full (python3-3.8.0)
  A high-level dynamically-typed programming language

$ nix search -u python39nix search -u python39 # is not found
error: no results for the given search term(s)!
```

Why can't I find/install this package? Is this a question of it "not being released to nix yet"? What should I do (or which documentation should I read) to install the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those nix commands look at your machine's `nixos` channel by default, which still points to a version of 19.09.

Your GitHub link references `master`, not `nixos-19.09`.

NixOS 19.09 is end-of-life, so you'll probably want to update to 20.09.